# How to get Mysql DB values to a json array in node js

Tags: node.js

How to get Mysql DB values to a json array in node js, Can anyone tell me the steps to follow to achieve this

Comment: Which libraries are you using?

Comment: I am a beginner for node js. I just wanted to know how this is done using the node js, Please share me the steps to achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're a beginner, here are the steps you need to perform:

1. You need to add a dependency to MySQL  to your project (e.g. [knex js](http://knexjs.org/)).
2. Then, you can use its `select()` promise to access the rows like in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/lucdew/10d7ab14a2b4db106285). To be more clear:

   ```
   return knex('books').select(knex.raw("data->'author' as author"))
     .whereRaw("data->'author'->>'first_name'=? ",[books[0].author.first_name])
     .then(function(rows) {

        // Here you have access to all rows as an array of objects 
        // which you can stringify

        console.log("Found "+rows.length+
          " books with authors first_name "+
          books[0].author.first_name);

        rows.forEach(function(row){
           console.log(row);
        });
     })
   ```

Comment: Can you specifically tell me in what cases we use a web service ? do we use web service instead of populating a web page data from database?

Comment: Hi, please open another question for this in order to avoid polluting this one with irrelevant discussions. If you're happy with the answer, please approve/upvote it.